# Tabela dinâmica em PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para acompanhamento de chamada e os professores precisam de um relatório onde será possível visualizar os alunos da turma filtrado por disciplina, onde será exibido se o aluno estava presente ou faltou naquele dias naquela disciplina.

Até aí tudo bem, o problema está sendo na hora de montar a tabela.

Eu preciso montar uma tabela onde os `<th></th>` das tabelas sejam preenchidos com algumas datas que estão no MySQL. Até aqui tudo bem, o problema é quando vou criar as linhas da tabela organizando o *status* da frequência com as respectivas datas, e tudo em uma linha só.

Hoje eu consigo exibir da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Precisava exibir ela da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

--------- EDIT

// Retorna as frequência dos alunos no bando de dados MySQL     public function

```
    frequencia()    {   
    $this->db->select('aluno_frequencia.af_InquilinoId,
                            aluno_frequencia.af_AnoLetivoId,
                            aluno_frequencia.af_PeriodoId,
                            aluno_frequencia.af_TurmaId,
                            aluno_frequencia.af_DisciplinaId,
                            aluno_frequencia.af_PessoaId,
                            aluno_frequencia.af_AlunoId,
                            anoletivo.anoletivo_Nome,
                            periodo.periodo_Nome,
                            turma.turma_Nome,
                            disciplina.disciplina_Nome,
                            apessoa.pessoa_Nome,
                            aluno_frequencia.af_data AS af_datahora,
                            DATE(aluno_frequencia.af_data) AS af_data,
                            aluno_frequencia.af_status');
            $this->db->from('aluno_frequencia');
            $this->db->join('aluno', 'aluno.aluno_id = aluno_frequencia.af_AlunoId');
            $this->db->join('pessoa AS apessoa', 'apessoa.pessoa_id = aluno.aluno_pessoa_id AND apessoa.pessoa_inquilino_id = aluno_frequencia.af_InquilinoId');
            $this->db->join('anoletivo', 'anoletivo.anoletivo_id = aluno_frequencia.af_AnoLetivoId AND anoletivo.anoletivo_inquilino_id = aluno_frequencia.af_InquilinoId');
            $this->db->join('periodo', 'periodo.periodo_inquilino_id = aluno_frequencia.af_InquilinoId AND periodo.periodo_id = aluno_frequencia.af_PeriodoId');
            $this->db->join('turma', 'turma.turma_inquilino_id = aluno_frequencia.af_InquilinoId AND turma.turma_id = aluno_frequencia.af_TurmaId');
            $this->db->join('disciplina', 'disciplina.disciplina_inquilino_id = aluno_frequencia.af_InquilinoId AND disciplina.disciplina_id = aluno_frequencia.af_DisciplinaId');
            $this->db->where('aluno_frequencia.af_InquilinoId', '2');
            $this->db->where('DATE(aluno_frequencia.af_data)', '2019-02-20');
            $this->db->where('aluno_frequencia.af_TurmaId', '25');
            $this->db->where('aluno_frequencia.af_DisciplinaId', '22');
            $this->db->order_by('aluno_frequencia.af_AlunoId', 'ASC');
            $query = $this->db->get();

            return $query->result();

            $this->db->close();     
}
```

// Retorna as datas das frequencias

```
public function dataFrequencia()
    {
        $this->db->select('DATE(aluno_frequencia.af_data) AS af_data');
        $this->db->from('aluno_frequencia');
        $this->db->join('aluno', 'aluno.aluno_id = aluno_frequencia.af_AlunoId');
        $this->db->join('pessoa AS apessoa', 'apessoa.pessoa_id = aluno.aluno_pessoa_id AND apessoa.pessoa_inquilino_id = aluno_frequencia.af_InquilinoId');
        $this->db->join('anoletivo', 'anoletivo.anoletivo_id = aluno_frequencia.af_AnoLetivoId AND anoletivo.anoletivo_inquilino_id = aluno_frequencia.af_InquilinoId');
        $this->db->join('periodo', 'periodo.periodo_inquilino_id = aluno_frequencia.af_InquilinoId AND periodo.periodo_id = aluno_frequencia.af_PeriodoId');
        $this->db->join('turma', 'turma.turma_inquilino_id = aluno_frequencia.af_InquilinoId AND turma.turma_id = aluno_frequencia.af_TurmaId');
        $this->db->join('disciplina', 'disciplina.disciplina_inquilino_id = aluno_frequencia.af_InquilinoId AND disciplina.disciplina_id = aluno_frequencia.af_DisciplinaId');
        $this->db->where('aluno_frequencia.af_InquilinoId', '2');
        $this->db->where('DATE(aluno_frequencia.af_data)', '2019-02-20');
        $this->db->where('aluno_frequencia.af_TurmaId', '25');
        $this->db->where('aluno_frequencia.af_DisciplinaId', '22');
        $this->db->group_by('aluno_frequencia.af_AlunoId');
        $this->db->order_by('aluno_frequencia.af_AlunoId', 'ASC');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();

        $this->db->close();
    }
```

// Retorna os alunos da turma
public function alunoTurma()
    {

```
    $this->db->select('aluno.aluno_id,
                    aluno.aluno_pessoa_id,
                    apessoa.pessoa_Nome');
    $this->db->from('aluno');
    $this->db->join('pessoa AS apessoa', 'apessoa.pessoa_id = aluno.aluno_pessoa_id');
    $this->db->join('turma_aluno', 'turma_aluno.taluno_Aluno_id = aluno.aluno_id');
    $this->db->join('turma_periodo', ' turma_periodo.tp_id = turma_aluno.taluno_TurmaPeriodo_id AND turma_periodo.tp_anoletivo_id = aluno.aluno_anoletivo_id AND turma_periodo.tp_periodo_id = aluno.aluno_periodo_id');
    $this->db->join('turma', 'turma.turma_id = turma_periodo.tp_turma_id AND turma.turma_inquilino_id = apessoa.pessoa_inquilino_id');
    $this->db->where('apessoa.pessoa_inquilino_id', '2');
    $this->db->where('turma.turma_id', '25');
    $this->db->order_by('apessoa.pessoa_Nome', 'ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();

    $this->db->close();

}
```

// Estou tentando agrupas as informações em um array primeiro para depois montar a tabela totalmente dinamina

```
$tabela['CABECALHO'] = array();
$tabela['LINHA'] = array();
$tabela['LINHA']['FREQUENCIA'] = array();

foreach($dataFrequencia as $DataFrequencia)
{

    array_push($tabela['CABECALHO'], $DataFrequencia->af_data);


}

foreach($alunoTurma as $AlunoTurma)
{

    foreach($frequencia as $Frequencia)
    {

        if($AlunoTurma->aluno_id == $Frequencia->af_AlunoId)
        {

            $linha = array('DATA' => $DataFrequencia->af_data, 'ALUNO' => $AlunoTurma->pessoa_Nome );
            array_push($tabela['LINHA'], $linha);

        }

    }

}
```

Eu até consegui agrupar as informações da forma que eu quero, mas é direto no mysql e eu achei um pouco trabalhoso, o SQL fica gigante e acho que isso acaba prejudicando o desempenhom segue o SQL que montei....

```
SELECT
aluno.aluno_id,
apessoa.pessoa_Nome,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(aluno_frequencia.af_data, ' ', aluno_frequencia.af_status)) AS status FROM aluno_frequencia WHERE aluno_frequencia.af_AlunoId = aluno.aluno_id AND aluno_frequencia.af_TurmaId = 25 AND aluno_frequencia.af_DisciplinaId = 22 AND DATE(aluno_frequencia.af_data) = '2019-02-20') AS '20/02'
FROM aluno
JOIN pessoa AS apessoa ON apessoa.pessoa_id = aluno.aluno_pessoa_id
WHERE aluno.aluno_id IN (SELECT vwturmaaluno.aluno_id FROM vwturmaaluno WHERE vwturmaaluno.turma_id = 25)
AND
aluno.aluno_id IN (SELECT vwdisciplinaaluno.aluno_id FROM vwdisciplinaaluno WHERE vwdisciplinaaluno.disciplina_id = 22)
```

Comment: Olá @Danillo Dars, adicione a pergunta a estrutura da tabela e também o seu código SQL para que possamos auxiliar na solução. Sem isso só vamos conseguir supor soluções em cima de tabelas pressupostas.

Comment: O código SQL que está a usar de certeza é que está incorreto. Edite a sua questão e coloque aí o código, será muito mais fácil ajudar.

Comment: Cara cola aqui sua query, mas desconfio que falta um GROUP BY aluno ai.

Comment: provavel que voce esta dando JOIN das disciplinas e por isso ta vindo varios alunos "repetidos". O aluno tem N disciplinas. Mas sem a query fica dificil.

Comment: As query's foram inseridas como sol citado, mas vale lembrar que até o cabeçalho da tabela é dinâmico.